# Changing field and master in mathematics

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, changing-fields, europe

Now I am studying engineering.But i want to do master in mathematics in Europe.The only math classes I've taken are linear algebra and calculus.Where should I start and what should I do?

Comment: Would you consider an applied math field that could be a little closer to engineering?

Comment: It seems to should reach out to the university you aim and ask at which year they would take you in. It could be second year of B.Sc, but it would depend on the actual content of your courses and grades you got. I would not expect to enter in Master before having first taken up studies in mathematics.

Comment: Thank you for answer.I want to learn math topics online and get  certificates.Is it bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Warning:* I am judging from my Math course which was finished 10 years ago well before introduction of the BSc-/MSc-system to Europe. German *Diplom* holder here.

---

You would miss quite a lot.

- Firstly, I'd think that your calculus course might not be on par in at least some areas. "Calculus fit for MSc" means for me Calculus I, Calculus II, and Calculus III with less emphasis on it.
- Algebra. All of it. To give you a simple test, "what is the actual reason, polynomial equations in single variable of degree higher than four are not solvable in radicals?" Does it ring a bell? You should be able to name a very concrete reason as a math MSc student. Heck, actually, as a second-year BSc student, too.
- Applied maths. You *might* know some of it through your specialisation, but your destination university might want proofs. Typically, it's either Statistics or Numerical Mathematics.
- Some kind of a deeper application course, like Differential Equations, Geometry, or Number Theory. Advanced Algebra, more Numerical Maths (like Approximation theory or something) might also work.

---

What you seem to have looks to me as an equivalent of a *minor* in math. While it's Ok, and it worked out for some, you might want to deepen your knowledge.

In a somewhat relatable effort, I dived into a PhD in computer science after what would be now a MSc in Applied Mathematics (with a minor in CS). It was doable, but in parts tough. Still, be different background gave me an unique view on some things, so there is some good side to it too.